# What is the story of Grihpati avatar of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, avatars

What is the story of Grihpati avatar of Lord Shiva? Why was he born and who were his parents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Brahmin named Visvanara and his wife Shuchismati lived on the banks of Narmada river. Even after a long period of married life, they did not have a child.  So proceeded to Kashi and prayed to Lord Siva. Siva appeared before Visvanara, blessed him and promises to taken birth as their son.

In due course of time, Shuchismati gave birth to a beautiful child.Lord Brahma named the child as Grihapati.  He started learning the Vedas in the traditional way and within one year, he became proficient in all the Vedas and other sacred texts.

When Grihapati attained the age of nine, Narada came and said that Grihapati would have a fear of fire. Grihapati then consoled his parents and proceeded to Kasi to do penance in order to avoid death. In Kasi, Grihapati found out an auspicious place and placed a Shivalinga there. Beside the Sivaling, he commenced his penance with prayers.

On knowing about the act of Grihapati, Lord Indra arrived there and blessed him. He requested him to demand anything he wished as boon. However, Grihapati refused to demand anything. Indra became furious upon this and tried to attack him with his Vajrayudha (weapon Vajra). Grihapati was very much frightened. He prayed to Lord Shiva for protection.

Immediately, Lord Siva appeared before him. On seeing Bholenath, Indra was forced to retreat from the scene. Mahadeva blessed Grihapati and said – “Do not be afraid of this Vajra of Indra. No Vajra would be able to kill you” and then Grihapati was become a agni.

The Linga that Grihapati adorned was known as Agnishvara in Kashi.

> Chapter.13 (Section 3 - Śatarudra-saṃhitā of Shiva Purana)

> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226409.html

Comment: There is also a story about Agnideva giving curse to grihapati

Comment: This is a very interesting incident. Although I know this is a very stupid question, what happens if a man gets to have a boon, and he ask for infinite wishes? Is this wish granted to him?

Comment: @codeczar: you can post your answer quoting the story known to you :-)

Comment: @Shashwat: very tricky question :-).  It depends on the Almighty's wish at that time.

Comment: @codeczar: A blog says Agni tried to burn up Grihapati  but Shiva saves him in the form of Indra.https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.tellyupdate.co.in/28/05/2019/vighnaharta-ganesh-28th-may-2019-written-episode-update-grihapati-prays-to-shiv-ling.html/amp)

Comment: In vedic literature Agni was described as grihapati ( https://www.srichinmoylibrary.com/dcg-6). In Shiva purana a story of a child by the name grihapati was woven.  Likewise many epithets ,which used to describe the Almighty , were used to create stories in different Puranas. @codeczar